# The soft keyboard hides part of the TextInputLayout when used In a TextInputEditText. How do I adjust the panning?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-textinputlayout

I've got a `TextInputLayout` with a `TextInputEditText` inside. This works nicely, specifically for error-displaying purposes (whenever I need to display an error on the text field, I just call `setError("error message")` and the error message is displayed under the EditText.

### The problem

The problem is that the keyboard usually hides this error, especially if the screen has to pan down to reveal the EditText. Check out what I mean in the screenshots below:

[image]

See how when the lower field is focused, the error message is hidden? I have to manually scroll down:

[image]

### Question

How do I tell the framework to pan down to the bottom of *the `TextInputLayout`*, **instead** of the `TextInputEditText` when the field is focused?

For reference, here's my layout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/clearable_edittext_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/clearable_edit_text_height"
    android:background="@drawable/clearable_edit_text_background">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/large_padding"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:labelFor="@id/clearable_text"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/clear_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/clearable_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@null"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:saveEnabled="false"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="@color/new_grey_2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_18"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clear_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/default_string"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/large_padding"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/small_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/icn_clear"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For other persons landing in this page, i had a similar issue but TextinputLayouts are in a RecyclerView item layout.
I had to add this to my Fragment:

```
//editableFields is my RecyclerView instance
binding.editableFields.addOnLayoutChangeListener((v, left, top, right, bottom, oldLeft, oldTop, oldRight, oldBottom) -> {
        //Without this code, the helper or Error message is hidden for the last recyclerview item when autoscroll occurs with keyboard shown...
        View viewChild=binding.editableFields.getFocusedChild();
        if(viewChild!=null) {
            //Define the child Rectangle that must be fully visible on the screen
            Rect clip=new Rect(viewChild.getLeft(),viewChild.getTop(),viewChild.getRight(),viewChild.getHeight());
           //Request to show the rectangle on the screen. last param only defines if you want to animate the scroll or not...
           binding.editableFields.requestChildRectangleOnScreen(viewChild,clip,true);
        }
    });
```

Maybe this could help even outside of a RecyclerView.